# Construct url to display a specific size

Tags: magento2

I have a product with 3 sizes, small medium and large.
Is there a way to construct the product url so a customer will land on the pdp page with “large” already selected? Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible with core Magento functionalities, but definitely possible to implement. I would suggest to add new size parameter to the configurable product url and catch it when product view is is loaded.

Comment: Ok cool, I will try that and post back

Comment: Your requirement is about diffrent URL or the pre selected options?